# How do you access the store within a route guard with vue SSR?

Tags: vuex, vue-router, vue-ssr

I'm using Vue + SSR on a new project and I'm trying to implement a route guard to enforce authentication on certain routes. I want to do something like this:

```
function requireAuth(to, from, next) {

  if(!store.auth.getters.authenticated){
  // redirect to login
  }

  ...
}
```

However, I can't simply `import` the store as in a normal app since I'm creating a fresh instance for each request, inside of a function, as per [the official docs](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/routing.html#code-splitting).

```
export function createRouter () {
  return new Router({
  ...
  });
}
```

Is there any way of passing the store to the route guard? Or am I coming at this from completely the wrong angle? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `import` statements are used at compile time. If you import `store` at the top of your router, it should be available within the `requireAuth()` function. Or am I missing the point?

Comment: @RichardMatsen unfortunately the store is not directly exported from the `store/index.js'. When using SSR, you need to create a fresh instance for each request, so the store is returned from a factory method.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found a solution, but it's not the most elegant. Inspired by [this comment on GitHub](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/2118#issuecomment-409052369)...

```
 # router/index.js
createRouter(store) {

  const router = new Router({
    mode: "history",
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/some-protected-route",
        beforeEnter: requireAuth.bind(store)
      }

    ...
  });

  return router;
}

...

requireAuth(to, from, next) {
  const store = this;

  if(!store.getters["auth/authenticated"]) { ... }
}
```

And don't forget to pass the store into the createRouter function:

```
# app.js

export default function createApp() {

  const store = createStore();
  const router = createRouter(store);

  sync(store,router)

  const app = new Vue({
    router,
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
  });

  return { app, router, store };
}
```

Also make sure to avoid / mitigate any browser-only code in the underlying logic.

Comment: The router depends on the store to determine how it should route, so I don't see any inelegance with doing it this way.  You can only decouple so much.